# How to interpret results of calling proc_listpids function on MacOS?

Tags: c, swift, macos

I'm trying to get list of pids on **MacOS**. *librpoc.h* contains this function signature but I cannot find any documentation:

```
int proc_listpids(uint32_t type, uint32_t typeinfo, void *buffer, int buffersize) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_2_0);
```

I tried this sample code in **Swift**:

```swift
let arr = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(byteCount: 5000 * MemoryLayout<Int32>.stride, alignment: MemoryLayout<Int32>.alignment)
let count = proc_listpids(UInt32(PROC_ALL_PIDS), 0, arr, Int32(5000 * MemoryLayout<Int32>.stride));
print("count \(count)")

let pointer = arr.assumingMemoryBound(to: Int32.self)
let pids = Array(UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start:pointer, count:Int(count)))
let slice = pids[0..<Int(count)]
for i in 0..<Int(count) {
     print("index:\(i) pid:\(slice[i])")
}
```

Initially I thought that `count` is the number of pids found. But the output shows more elements:

```
count 2020
index:0 pid:7727
index:1 pid:7726
index:2 pid:7723
index:3 pid:7722
index:4 pid:7721
index:5 pid:7717
...
index:502 pid:94
index:503 pid:1
index:504 pid:0
index:505 pid:0
index:506 pid:0
...
index:2013 pid:0
index:2014 pid:0
index:2015 pid:0
index:2016 pid:0
index:2017 pid:0
index:2018 pid:0
index:2019 pid:0
```

So it's confusing how to interpret the number that `proc_listpids` actually returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The issue

`proc_listpids` (and many other `libproc.h` API)s return the total buffer size *in bytes* that the result will have. So the result `2020` is `2020` bytes, which is exactly enough to store `505` `Int32`s (4 bytes each, of course), meaning the last valid index is `504`.

## Why does it return a size and not a count?

This is just speculation on my part, but I suspect that it's because it makes the API convenient for use in C, where this result will likely be passed directly to `malloc`.

If they returned a count instead of a number of bytes, callers would have to convert it over themselves. Since a lot of libproc APIs can return one of several different structures, using `sizeof` with the wrong structure (for the particular type of request you're marking) can lead to a buffer that's too small (risking buffer-overflow vulnerabilities) or too large (risking buffer-underflow vulnerabilities).

## Working examples

Here's a snippet showing a working call to `proc_listpids`:

```swift
func getAllPIDs1() -> [pid_t] {
    let expectedSize = proc_listpids(UInt32(PROC_ALL_PIDS), 0, nil, 0)

    guard expectedSize != -1 else {
        fatalError("Something went wrong... but what exactly?")
    }

    let stride = Int32(MemoryLayout<pid_t>.stride)
    let expectedCount = Int(expectedSize / stride)

    return Array(unsafeUninitializedCapacity: expectedCount) { buffer, initializedCount in
        let initializedSize = proc_listpids(UInt32(PROC_ALL_PIDS), 0, &buffer, Int32(initializedCount))
        initializedCount = Int(initializedSize / stride)
    }
}
```

Things get a bit simpler if you use `proc_listallpids`, which is just an convenience wrapper for this case ([source](https://github.com/apple-opensource/xnu/blob/4f43d4276fc6a87f2461a3ab18287e4a2e5a1cc0/libsyscall/wrappers/libproc/libproc.c#L62-L73)):

```swift
func getAllPIDs2() -> [pid_t] {
    let exptectedCount = proc_listallpids(nil, 0)

    guard exptectedCount != -1 else {
        fatalError("Something went wrong... but what exactly?")
    }

    let expectedSize = Int(exptectedCount) * MemoryLayout<pid_t>.stride

    return Array(unsafeUninitializedCapacity: expectedSize) { buffer, initializedCount in
        initializedCount = Int(proc_listallpids(&buffer, Int32(initializedCount)))
    }
}
```

Some notes:

1. Both of these "right-size" the array, which sounds ideal, but has a catch

   - If a new process starts in the period between the first and second call to
     `proc_listpids`, then your buffer would be too small to fit it.

     - These two calls usually happen in very rapid succession (so this would be unlikely), it could be longer if your process get preempted and suspended between the calls, leaving more change for this to occur.
   - Perhaps it's best to use the result of `proc_listpids` for an
     initial guess of the size, and then add some extra to account for
     any new processes that might pop up.
2. You can use [`Array.init(unsafeUninitializedCapacity:initializingWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/init(unsafeuninitializedcapacity:initializingwith:)) to allocate a buffer for a Swift Array, and initialize it directly, without any intermediate allocations or copies.

   - Beware, this API is basically like `malloc`, and misuse can lead
     huge issues.

## Extra

If you find yourself calling many different libproc APIs, I found it useful to define a helper to abstract away parts of this dance (such as these count calculations, integer casts, assertions, etc.):

```swift
private func extractIntoArray<T>(
    of _: T.Type,
    expectedSize: Int32,
    using body: (UnsafeMutablePointer<T>) throws -> Int32
) rethrows -> [T] {
    let stride = Int32(MemoryLayout<T>.stride)
    // Sanity check: this can catch a lot of cases where you provide the wrong
    // expected structure for the particular "type" of call you're making.
    assert(expectedSize.isMultiple(of: stride))
    let expectedCount = Int(expectedSize / stride)

    return try Array(unsafeUninitializedCapacity: expectedCount) { buffer, initializedCount in
        let initializedSize = try body(buffer.baseAddress!)
        assert(initializedSize.isMultiple(of: stride))
        initializedCount = Int(initializedSize / stride)
    }
}

struct LibProcError: Error {}

func getAllPIDs() throws -> [pid_t] {
    let bufferSize = proc_listpids(UInt32(PROC_ALL_PIDS), 0, nil, 0)

    guard bufferSize != -1 else {
        throw LibProcError()
    }
    
    return try extractIntoArray(of: pid_t.self, expectedSize: bufferSize, using: { bufferP in
        proc_listpids(UInt32(PROC_ALL_PIDS), 0, &buffer, Int32(initializedCount))
    })
}
```